# Erro ao tentar carregar uma mat-table com angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-6

Começando com Angular 6. Ao tentar criar uma table, baseado em um exemplo que peguei, comecei a ter o seguinte problema. Acrescentei em meu **module** principal, essas linhas:

```
import { MatInputModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule, 
         MatSortModule, MatTableModule } from '@angular/material';
```

e na seção **imports** acrescentei também, conforme abaixo:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule
  ],
```

Bem, acontece que nessa linha tenho o seguinte erro:

```
from '@angular/material';
```

> [ts] Cannot find module '@angular/material'.

E também nos imports, dá erro nesses dois caras

```
BrowserAnimationsModule,
HttpClientModule,
```

Então o que eu fiz. Fui no **package.json** da aplicação e acrescentei essa linha:

```
"@angular/material": "^6.0.3",
```

bem, de qualquer forma persiste o erro. Alguém já passou por isso e conseguiu resolver? Estou pesquisando, mas até agora nenhuma resposta conclusiva.

Comment: bem, acabei de achar um link e vou testar a resposta dos caras e ver o que acontece.

Comment: Chegasse a dar um npm install após inserir a linha no package.json ?

Comment: @LucasBrogni, sim fiz isso agora. Não resolveu, mas não reiniciei o VS Code. Vou fazer isso agora. Fiz: **npm install --save @angular/material**

Comment: fiz agora **npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk** vou ver se resolveu

Comment: ainda persiste, mesmo reiniciando o VS Code

Answer (score 1):

Pela documentação do angular material cada import tem seu próprio path. Isso pra tentar ser o mais modular possível. Por Exemplo:

```
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
```

Comment: Eduardo, como eu fiz assim os imports: **import { MatInputModule, MatPaginatorModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule, MatSortModule, MatTableModule } from '@angular/material';** devo fatiar um por vez?

Comment: isso de cada um deles

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/input/api

Comment: So ver a tab api de cada componente

Comment: Reinstalei o @angular/material e desta vez ele funcionou. E não sei porque ontem não, ontem eu dei um **npm install g @angular/material --save** e hoje eu removi o g. Acho que foi isso.